# How to split table in different range and select 1000 random rows from each split table and join in one table in sql

Tags: mysql, pyspark, hive

I want to split table in bins and then select random 1000 rows from each splitted table and join these rows to final table.

in pyspark i can do like this

```
df1 = (df.where((df.A >1)&(df.A <10)))
df1=df1.orderBy(F.rand()).limit(1000)
df2 = (df.where((df.A >10)&(df.A <20)))
df2=df2.orderBy(F.rand()).limit(1000)

dfs = [df1, df2]
df_complete = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

how to do this in sql ?

Comment: So your goal is to take groups of 1000's records, and sort those groups randomly?

Comment: @Evert my main goal is to split table in bins ,if column A value between 1 to 10  make it BIN_1 then if column A value between 10 to 20  make it BIN_2 then  randomly select 1000 values fron BIN_1 and putt these 1000 values to final table ,,, do Same thing for all BIN

Comment: is it mysql or hive ? do you need in spark or hive ql should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql syntax, assuming new_t has the same structure:

```
insert into new_t 
select * from t where {condition 1} order by rand() limit 1000
union
select * from t where {condition 2} order by rand() limit 1000
```